# Why is text-align:right not working in this case?

Tags: html, css

I am not sure if it's okay to post a site URL but I will try anyway. I am trying to get the phone number at the top of this site (https://maisons-keyho.com/) aligned to the right. I thought the text-align property on the block-level element (parent div) should do the trick but it isn't working.

[image]

The following simplified code however works

```
<div class="header header_component header_component--linktext la_compt_iem la_com_action--linktext  strong" style="text-align:right">
        <a rel="nofollow" class="component-target" href="tel:0450775238">
            <span class="component-target-text">Appelez-nous au 04 50 77 52 38</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Could anybody please help me understand why it's not working on the site ? and how do I align it to the right ? I don't have access to the HTML of the code and would need to do it using CSS only.

Comment: I have copied your code to a HTML page I am working on and the phone number does appear on the right hand side. I used Firefox to test. And your `text-align: right` is definitely making that happen as it moves to the left if I remove that style.

Comment: Maybe it's because of some other CSS ( since you only copied the HTML) . Does it work for you on the actual site ?  In the actual site (https://maisons-keyho.com/) if I do text-align: right using Chrome Inspector it doesn't work. I edited my screenshot to highlight how I am adding the code using Inspector .

Comment: I did look at your link and as you mentioned, the phone number does appear on the left. So yes, I would guess that in your CSS is something over-riding your `text-align:right`. I wonder if this could be a global CSS instruction on `<a>` tags or `<span>` tags (both inside your parent div).

Comment: You are right, the <a> tag is set to block. But I tried changing everything to inline without any success.

Comment: Just as a test and to eliminate things, try it all without inline or block, the natural behaviour (which is probably inline or block regardless) might be what you need. As I was saying, it looks perfect on mine without using the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it out. When you change width of parent div to 100% and align it to right. Then this property is working.

Reason: As far as I know, this property depends upon the width of the element on which this is applied to. When you make the width of parent div 100%, which means its width is equal to its parent element which in this case is the whole width of header.

Link element is inline by default.So, if you apply the property to the parent element it will work.

This might be confusing but if you have doubts please let me know.

[Have a look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3T86.png)

Comment: I found the same on Firefox inspector. The span element is filling the width of its parent div element so will not appear to move unless the parent div is set to be the full width of its container.

Comment: funny how this site works ;-)

Comment: Yes @DavePritlove. This is the main reason why the property wasn't working. I did a bad job at explaining it but you NAILED it!!

Comment: Learned something new . The div(header_component header_component--linktext la_compt_iem la_com_action--linktext  strong) is floated . So eventhough its block element its width is equal to the content inside (100% otherwise). So text-align it is'nt working . One way would be to make it 100% like @RishavSharma suggested.